# Laravel set parent route group parameters from child route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

How I can set parent route parameter from child route group?Is it possible.
My parameter is {locale} and child route is projects.single .
I have tried this code, but it does not work:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => '{locale}',
'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
'middleware' => 'setlocale'
], function () {
   Auth::routes();
   Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
   });
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
   Route::group(['prefix' => '/projects', 'as' => 'projects.'], function () {
      Route::get('/', 'ProjectController@index')->name('archive');
      Route::get('/{slug}', 'ProjectController@showSingle')->name('single');
   });
});
```

In header.blade.php view I use this code for link href:

```
{{-- @foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $locale)
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), $locale) }}"
                       @if (app()->getLocale() == $locale) style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" @endif>{{ strtoupper($locale) }}</a>
     </li>
 @endforeach--}}
```

This code gives this error message Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.single] [URI: {locale}/projects/{slug}]. (View: /home/wa/pi/resources/views/includes/header.blade.php) (View: /home/wa/pi/resources/views/includes/header.blade.php) (View: /home/wa/pi/resources/views/includes/header.blade.php)

Comment: What about: `route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['locale' => $locale])` ?

Comment: I`m giving the href link to the same current route but with a different language – for that  using Route::currentRouteName() method

Comment: But when I`m  using this function it return child rute like 'project.single' where is not exist 'local' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

i don't now how to set parameters in child route but your {locale} parameter is available all methods in your controllers.
For example

```
public function ($locale) { // $locale is the same with {locale} in your route
    // something
}
```